# Scala + Intellij syntax highlighting issues

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Currently I have a simple scala project.

Running `sbt compile` from the command line succeeds
In Intellij doing `Build > Rebuild Project` the build will succeed.

However there are several issues with syntax highlighting.

Receive types are not being recognized, `context.become(<some Receive def>)` is failing (this is due to Receive not being recognized), and lots of other issues that are seemingly random.

Current `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at 
"http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core" % "10.0.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.0.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.5.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.1",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.5.1" % "test"
)
```

I've tried invalidating my cache and restarting, didn't work.
I've updated Intellij. I tried wiping my .idea files and re-importing the project.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: I just learned to live with the fact that when intelliJ says that a `.sbt` file contains a syntax error, intellij might be wrong :) hence when a "new" error appears I use the console to check if the `.sbt` files are free of syntax errors

Comment: it's not in the .sbt file, it's throughout my whole project. So I can't visually see if something is correct without rebuilding every time. It's also preventing a lot of auto-completion when writing code. I suppose I could just deal with it and pretend I'm writing node and just run the code to make sure it works/builds, however I like having auto-complete/syntax-highlighting working...

Comment: ah, do you have the scala sdk configured? (I had to tell intellij to configure it the first time I opened a scala project)

Comment: If I go to `Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies` it shows "Project SDK" as 1.8. I can't seem to find a way to create a scala sdk, I thought that was supposed to happen when you imported a project with SBT?

Comment: `Project structure` -> `Libraries` -> `+` -> `Scala SDK` -> choose one. I had to do the very first time I opened a scala project with intellij. Subsequent projects didn't require it.

Comment: I think I just need to nuke intellij on my mac book and remove all settings. I did a fresh install on my windows 10 machine and everything works just fine. :|